# CC alignment with scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I am trying to typeset a letter using Koma-Script, but the "distribution list" is not indented correctly. I would like it to look like in [Figure 4.7](https://komascript.de/%7Emkohm/scrguien.pdf#figure.4.7) in the documentation (I think it's called a "hanging indent"?).

I tried following the directions in the documentation, which say to "set the distribution list `\raggedright` and to separate the individual entries with a double backslash", but the result does not look like it should.

[image]

There was a [post](https://komascript.de/node/2237) a few years ago on `komascript.de` where something similar was described, and the answer was to use `\cc{...}`, but I am already doing that, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{An...}
       
  \opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

  \lipsum[1][1-5]
  \lipsum[2][1-5]

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}

\cc{\raggedright
  First person\\
  Second person}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```latex
\cc{%
  First person\\
  Second person
}
```

without `\raggedright`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{An...}
  \opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
  \lipsum[1][1-5]
  \lipsum[2][1-5]
  \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
  \cc{%
    First person\\
    Second person
  }
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]